# Redirect homepage to a different page using htaccess on a Drupal site

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

hoping you could give me some help. I'm trying to re-direct:

http://jaffajava.com/oldsite

To

http://jaffajava.com/oldsite/store

What I've tried so far:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jaffajava\.com/oldsite\$
  RewriteRule (.*) http://www.jaffajava.com/oldsite/store\$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help on correcting my syntax/code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why redirection? Just set new home page, in Configuration -> System -> Site information

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP_HOST` variable only matches domain name in the request. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^jaffajava\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldsite(/.*)?$ http://www.jaffajava.com/oldsite/store$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: See this is the issue... www.jaffajava.com is a different site completely, /oldsite/ is another site but in a different directory. I still want www.jaffajava.com available, but jaffajava.com/oldsite needs to be jaffajava.com/oldsite/store as I will be linking it from www.jaffajava.com